# Change select query to an update

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am having trouble changing the below select query to an update query. Please can someone help

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Test@' +(SELECT SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email))) as Email
,CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Media' as [Last Name]
from dbo.MPP_Inserts as MT
```

I have tried the below but get an error message saying:

> the windowed functions can appear in a select or order by clauses)

```
Update dbo.MPP_Inserts
Set Email = CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Test@' +(SELECT SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email)))
, [Last Name] = CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'DMG Media'
```

Comment: A first thing would be to remove the `from dbo.MPP_Inserts as MT` string at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you have updatable CTEs:

```
with toupdate as (
    SELECT mt.*,
           CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Test@' +(SELECT SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email))) as new_Email,
           CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Media' as new_lastname
    from dbo.MPP_Inserts MT
   )
update toupdate
    Set Email = new_email,
       [Last Name] = new_lastname;
```

The nested `select` in the substring is totally unnecessary, but I'm leaving the expressions unchanged so they are the same as in the query.  However, `new_email` could be expressed as:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)))) + 'Test@' +SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email) + 1, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email)) as new_Email,
```